# C++ finding uint8_t in vector<uint8_t>

Tags: c++, algorithm, find

I have the following simple code. I declare a vector and initialize it with one value 21 in this case. And then i am trying to find that value in the vector using find. I can see that the element "21" in this case is in the vector since i print it in the for loop. However why the iterator of find does not resolve to true?

```
vector<uint8_t> v =  { 21 };
uint8_t valueToSearch = 21;


for (vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i){
    cout << unsigned(*i) << ' ' << endl;
}


auto it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), valueToSearch);
if ( it != v.end() )
{
    string m = "valueToSearch was found in the vector " + valueToSearch;
    cout << m << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure it doesn't work?

I just tried it:

```
#include<iostream> // std::cout
#include<vector> 
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<uint8_t> v =  { 21 };
    uint8_t valueToSearch = 21;


    for (vector<uint8_t>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i){
        cout << unsigned(*i) << ' ' << endl;
    }


    auto it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), valueToSearch);
    if ( it != v.end() )
    {// if we hit this condition, we found the element
        string error = "valueToSearch was found in the vector ";
        cout << error <<  int(valueToSearch) << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

There are two small modifications:

- in the last lines inside the "if", because you cannot add directly a
  number to a string:

  `string m = "valueToSearch was found in the vector " + valueToSearch;`

and it prints:

```
21 
valueToSearch was found in the vector 21
```

- while it's true that you cannot add a number to a string, cout
  support the insertion operator (<<) for int types, but not uint8_t,
  so you need to convert it to it.

  `cout << error <<  int(valueToSearch) << endl;`

This to say that the find is working correctly, and it is telling you that it found the number in the first position, and for this, `it != end` (end is not a valid element, but is a valid iterator that marks the end of your container.)

Try it [here](http://cpp.sh/2qfcx)

Comment: crsn i am running this code in google test and for some reason it does not print. , however after your answer i just tried in clean hello world  using  to_string(valueToSearch) and it does print.

Comment: sorry to bother i might have to make a clean rebuild of the whole project

Comment: that would explain it :)